# Error : type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast

Tags: json, dart

I have a response

```
 [{details: {macId:789101112}}]
```

jsonData['details']  will return String {macId:789101112}

Parsing code :

```
fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> jsonData) => User(
        details: UserDetails.fromJson(jsonData['details'] as Map<String, dynamic>),
      );


class UserDetails{
 final String macId;
 UserDetails({this.macId});

 static UserDetails fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
     UserDetails(macId: json['macId'] as String);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at the original source. From your description, it sounds like it looks something like:

```json
[{"details": "{\"macId\": 789101112}"}]
```

That is, the *value* of the `"details"` entry is a *string* containing JSON source code.

You will need to parse that a second time:

```dart
fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> jsonData) => 
  User(details: UserDetails.fromJson(jsonDecode(jsonData['details'])));
```

The reason for this is likely that the place where the you generate JSON data from `UserDetails` object, it calls `jsonEncode` on the map, and it should not do that. Just let the `UserDetails`-to-JSON function return a map, so that that map can be embedded in the larger JSON-like data structure. Then you won't need the second `jsonDecode` either.